# Huawei P8 Lite Wifi Problem

Tags: wi-fi, huawei

Huawei P8 lite ALE-L21. Since yesterday Wi-Fi did stop working. To be more precise, I see my wi-fi network but I can not connect to it. I receive a "saved, secured" messaged and if I insist I get "denied access to network". I day before, same installation did work. Now I did try to configure a unprotected wi-fi network, it dos not work anymore. I did also try to hard reset my phone, wipe all cache but the issue didn't resolve. I assume now that this is a hardare issue related to the L21. Android Version is 5.0.1

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as you. Tried EVERYTHING. Even updated my Android to 6.0 and EMUI to 4.0. Did you have any luck in solving this problem?